# Remove Null Values from Left join MYSQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have this data base and I execute Left Join on it and i have Null Values and i want to remove these null values. I'm Attaching my Database & PHP Script which shows the Query.

If anyone Can Help me With removing Null Values from JSON please?
I want retrieve all the news that a user is interested in depending on the interested teams table.

**teaminterest Table**

```
teaminterests_id |userName  |teamName     
-------------------------------------------------
1                | Tomas         | Real Madrid       
--------------------------------------------------
2                | Tomas         | FCB. Barcelona
--------------------------------------------------
3                | Carl          | Real Madrid
```

**teamnews Table**

```
    teamnews_id |teamnews_title     |teamnews_image|teamnews_text|teamnews_timeStamp |teamnews_newsURL   |TeamName
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    3           | Barcelona News 1  | XYZ.jpg      | Dummy Text  |2016-04-23 17:51:23| Dummy Website.com | FCB. Barcelona 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    4           | RealMadrid News1  | ZYX.jpg      | Dummy Text  |2016-04-23 17:51:23| Dummy Website.com | Real Madrid 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    5           | RealMadrid News2  | ZYX.jpg      | Dummy Text  |2016-04-23 17:51:23| Dummy Website.com | Real Madrid  
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    6           | RealMadrid News3  | ZYX.jpg      | Dummy Text  |2016-04-23 17:51:23| Dummy Website.com | Real Madrid 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    7           | Barcelona News 2  | XYZ.jpg      | Dummy Text  |2016-04-23 17:51:23| Dummy Website.com | FCB. Barcelona
```

And if i Send This URL to this PHP SCRIPT

**http://localhost/HiFootball/NewsFragment/test.php?userName=tomas**

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php

require('C:\wamp\www\HiFootball\config.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);



    $query="
   select  distinct * 

    from teaminterest

    left join teamnews   

    on  teaminterest.userName='".$_GET['userName']."'  and teamnews.TeamName=teaminterest.teamName 
    order by teamnews_timeStamp desc
    ";


$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$rows = array();
echo mysqli_error($conn);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $rows[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($rows);


?>
```

I get this JSON FORM:

```
   [
{"teaminterests_id":"104","userName":"Tomas","teamName":"Real Madrid","teamnews_id":"4","teamnews_title":"Real Madrid News 1 ","teamnews_image":"ZYX.jpg","teamnews_text":"Dummy Text","teamnews_timeStamp":"2016-04-23 17:52:23","teamnews_newsURL":"www.DummWebsite.com","TeamName":"Real Madrid"}
,
{"teaminterests_id":"104","userName":"Tomas","teamName":"Real Madrid","teamnews_id":"6","teamnews_title":"Real Madrid News 2\r\n","teamnews_image":"ZYX.jpg","teamnews_text":"Dummy Text","teamnews_timeStamp":"2016-04-23 17:52:23","teamnews_newsURL":"www.DummWebsite.com","TeamName":"Real Madrid"}
,
{"teaminterests_id":"104","userName":"Tomas","teamName":"Real Madrid","teamnews_id":"7","teamnews_title":"Real Madrid News 3","teamnews_image":"ZYX.jpg","teamnews_text":"Dummy Text","teamnews_timeStamp":"2016-04-23 17:52:23","teamnews_newsURL":"www.DummWebsite.com","TeamName":"Real Madrid"}
,{"teaminterests_id":"103","userName":"Tomas","teamName":"Barca","teamnews_id":"3","teamnews_title":"Barcelona News 1 ","teamnews_image":"XYZ.jpg","teamnews_text":"Dummy Text","teamnews_timeStamp":"2016-04-23 17:51:23","teamnews_newsURL":"WWW.dummywebsite.com","TeamName":"Barca"}
,{"teaminterests_id":"103","userName":"Tomas","teamName":"Barca","teamnews_id":"8","teamnews_title":"Barcelona News 2","teamnews_image":"XYZ.jpg","teamnews_text":"Dummy Text","teamnews_timeStamp":"2016-04-23 17:51:23","teamnews_newsURL":"WWW.dummywebsite.com","TeamName":"Barca"}
,
{"teaminterests_id":"105","userName":"Carl","teamName":"Real Madrid","teamnews_id":null,"teamnews_title":null,"teamnews_image":null,"teamnews_text":null,"teamnews_timeStamp":null,"teamnews_newsURL":null,"TeamName":null}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Move a part from `ON` tho `WHERE` and please use proper escaping of your SQL query.

```
$query="select  distinct * 
        from teaminterest
        left join teamnews   
            on teamnews.TeamName=teaminterest.teamName 
        where teaminterest.userName='".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['userName'])."' 
        order by teamnews_timeStamp desc
";
```